iPhone 14pro, Siri will not work when on car charger
I connect my iPhone to my car through Bluetooth, not CarPlay, just Bluetooth pairing. I use a MagSafe charging dock, connected to 12V lighter plug, not usb. Siri used to work fine, it suddenly stopped “hearing” for hey siri, but ONLY when on the charging dock. If I pull it off it, it hears and responds properly. The Bluetooth connection is fine, music keeps playing and all. Help
